# Asp.Net Identity - Unable to lock the account after 5 invalid attempts

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2

I am new to Asp.Net Identity 2.0. We have implemented functionality to lock the account after 5 successful invalid attempts. But currently the account is not getting locked out even though user reaches the max invalid attempts.

The  userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user1.Id) is always returning false.  Not sure what is the issue here.

Below is my code. Could you please help me out if I am doing anything wrong here.

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {


        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        var user1 = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);


        if (user1 != null)
        {

            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            // When a user is lockedout, this check is done to ensure that even if the credentials are valid
            // the user can not login until the lockout duration has passed
            if (await userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user1.Id))
            {
                context.SetError("", string.Format("Your account has been locked out for {0} minutes due to multiple failed login attempts.", userManager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout.ToString()));
                return;
            }
            // if user is subject to lockouts and the credentials are invalid
            // record the failure and check if user is lockedout and display message, otherwise, 
            // display the number of attempts remaining before lockout
            else if (await userManager.GetLockoutEnabledAsync(user1.Id) && user == null)
            {
                // Record the failure which also may cause the user to be locked out
                await userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user1.Id);

                string message;

                if (await userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user1.Id))
                {
                    message = string.Format("Your account has been locked out for {0} minutes due to multiple failed login attempts.", userManager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    int accessFailedCount = await userManager.GetAccessFailedCountAsync(user1.Id);

                    int attemptsLeft =
                        Convert.ToInt32(
                            userManager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout.ToString()) - accessFailedCount;

                    message = string.Format(
                        "Invalid credentials. You have {0} more attempt(s) before your account gets locked out.", attemptsLeft);

                }

                context.SetError("", message);
                return;

            }

            else if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The User ID or Password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            else if (!user.IsApproved)
            {
                context.SetError("Not Approved", "The user has to be approved manually by Admin.");
                return;
            }
            else
            {

                DataController datacontroller = new DataController();

                Contact vendor = datacontroller.CheckVendorIsActive(user.AccountNumber);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vendor.ApplicationUser.AccountNumber) && vendor.Description.ToLower().Equals("false"))
                {
                    context.SetError("Inactive User", "Sorry! Your account status is inactive. Please contact helpdesk for more support.");
                    return;
                }

                ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
                   OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);

                ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

                List<Claim> roles = oAuthIdentity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).ToList();

                AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(roles.Select(x => x.Value)), user.LastLoginDate.ToString(), user.AccountNumber, user.FirstName, user.LastName);

                AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
                context.Validated(ticket);
                context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);

                user.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now;

                await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

            }
        }
        else if (user1 == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The User ID or Password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Is your UserManager properly configured with: 
// Configure user lockout defaults
manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
?